# How to fill Listview with Object filled with Arraylist objects

Tags: android, listview, sticky

Service returns a object, and response object contains 5 6 Arraylist . I have to fill it to sticky header listview. How can I bind it to listview.

My sample response object is

```
public class ResponseSearch {

     private ArrayList<Book> books;
     private ArrayList<School> schools;
     private ArrayList<Magazine> magazines;
     private ArrayList<Education> educations;
     private ArrayList<Astrology> astrologies;
     private ArrayList<Movie> movies;
}
```

Comment: show your LISTVIEW image or POST your adapter ......

Comment: Go to a RecyclerView tutorial, it's your best option.

Comment: Post your JSON response and some android code Here...so that we can help you.

Comment: Post your JSON response and Adapter code here, So that we can get better idea

Answer (score 0):

http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/.
Refer this for recycler view because most of the new apps use this and if you wanna opt to list view,https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_list_view.htm or use vogella